# OAuth 2.0 Protocol Request from the client

Tags: oauth-2.0

RFC claims that (Figure 1):

> (A) The client requests authorization from the resource owner. The
> authorization request can be made directly to the resource owner
> (as shown), or preferably indirectly via the authorization
> server as an intermediary.

Does this mean that, upon request from the resource owner, an authentication protocol is not used?
Or what does it mean?

Comment: does "this" in your question refer to scenario that the authorization request is directly made to the resource owner or indirectly?

Comment: request is directly made to the owner in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, the RFC was a bit confusing to me. Direct vs indirect only means a different grant type is being used.

#### IMPORTANT

The following is for informational purposes, as [OAuth 2.0 best practices](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics) [(section link)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#name-resource-owner-password-cre) deprecate the use of direct authorization.

**Directly** means that the client will handle the resource owner's password credentials, treating them as a grant, and exchanging them for an access token by making a request to the authorization server:

> 1.3.3.  Resource Owner Password Credentials
>
> The resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password)
> can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access
> token.  The credentials should only be used when there is a high
> degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the
> client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged
> application), and when other authorization grant types are not
> available (such as an authorization code).
>
> Even though this grant type requires direct client access to the
> resource owner credentials, the resource owner credentials are used
> for a single request and are exchanged for an access token.  This
> grant type can eliminate the need for the client to store the
> resource owner credentials for future use, by exchanging the
> credentials with a long-lived access token or refresh token.

This is not preferred because it requires trusting the client to be a good steward of the credentials. For instance, the client should not be persisting the credentials, but you can't really know unless you can inspect its source.

**Indirectly** means that instead of trusting the client to be a good steward, we rely on HTTP redirection so that the client never even sees the credentials. Only the user agent will be able to see the credentials as they are entered.

From the RFC:

> The preferred method for the client to obtain an authorization grant
> from the resource owner (depicted in steps (A) and (B)) is to use the
> authorization server as an intermediary, which is illustrated in
> **Figure 3 in Section 4.1**.

```
4.1.  Authorization Code Grant

   The authorization code grant type is used to obtain both access
   tokens and refresh tokens and is optimized for confidential clients.
   Since this is a redirection-based flow, the client must be capable of
   interacting with the resource owner's user-agent (typically a web
   browser) and capable of receiving incoming requests (via redirection)
   from the authorization server.

     +----------+
     | Resource |
     |   Owner  |
     |          |
     +----------+
          ^
          |
         (B)
     +----|-----+          Client Identifier      +---------------+
     |         -+----(A)-- & Redirection URI ---->|               |
     |  User-   |                                 | Authorization |
     |  Agent  -+----(B)-- User authenticates --->|     Server    |
     |          |                                 |               |
     |         -+----(C)-- Authorization Code ---<|               |
     +-|----|---+                                 +---------------+
       |    |                                         ^      v
      (A)  (C)                                        |      |
       |    |                                         |      |
       ^    v                                         |      |
     +---------+                                      |      |
     |         |>---(D)-- Authorization Code ---------'      |
     |  Client |          & Redirection URI                  |
     |         |                                             |
     |         |<---(E)----- Access Token -------------------'
     +---------+       (w/ Optional Refresh Token)

   Note: The lines illustrating steps (A), (B), and (C) are broken into
   two parts as they pass through the user-agent.

                     Figure 3: Authorization Code Flow

   The flow illustrated in Figure 3 includes the following steps:

   (A)  The client initiates the flow by directing the resource owner's
        user-agent to the authorization endpoint.  The client includes
        its client identifier, requested scope, local state, and a
        redirection URI to which the authorization server will send the
        user-agent back once access is granted (or denied).

   (B)  The authorization server authenticates the resource owner (via
        the user-agent) and establishes whether the resource owner
        grants or denies the client's access request.

   (C)  Assuming the resource owner grants access, the authorization
        server redirects the user-agent back to the client using the
        redirection URI provided earlier (in the request or during
        client registration).  The redirection URI includes an
        authorization code and any local state provided by the client
        earlier.

   (D)  The client requests an access token from the authorization
        server's token endpoint by including the authorization code
        received in the previous step.  When making the request, the
        client authenticates with the authorization server.  The client
        includes the redirection URI used to obtain the authorization
        code for verification.

   (E)  The authorization server authenticates the client, validates the
        authorization code, and ensures that the redirection URI
        received matches the URI used to redirect the client in
        step (C).  If valid, the authorization server responds back with
        an access token and, optionally, a refresh token.
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that the client can request the resource onwer credentials in both ways:

- Directly to the resource owner, asking for user and password to the resource owner and then sending them to the authorization server,
- Or preferably via the authorization server, for example when you use your google or facebook account to authenticate in a web site.